# how to map two tables having pojos but relationship between them is defined in third table which does not have pojo

Tags: hibernate

i am using hibernate for a application.I have two tables with many-many relationship and I have POJOs for both of them.But the relationship is defined in third table which doesnot have POJO.How can i relate my two tables and use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have POJO for TableA and TableB and want to associate many-to-many relationship between them in Table C without creating POJO for TableC.

If Table C ONLY contains two columns which have the foreign key constraint to Table A and Table B , you can achieve it by using the `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable`:

```
@Entity
public class TableA{

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
        name = "TableC",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TableA_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TableB_ID")}
  )
  private List<TableB> tableB= new ArrayList<TableB>();

}

@Entity
public class TableB{

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tableB")
  private List<TableA> tableA= new ArrayList<TableA>();

}
```

But if Table C contains more additional columns that have no foreign key constraint to other tables (such as the column for `last_modified_date`) , you cannot do it and you must declare Table C as a POJO and [model the many-to-many association as two one-to-many associations to Table C](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/).